# Subplots in two separate figure windows inside one loop using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot two separate quantities while running through a loop. I want to create a separate figure window for each quantity, such that each iteration of the loop creates one subplot for each quantity.

Basically, I want my code to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nr = [10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 50]
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
for y in range(len(nr)):
        m = np.arange(y+1)
        n = (y+1)*np.arange(y+1)
        fig1.subplot(3,2,y+1)
        fig1.plot(m,n, 'b')
        fig1.title('y=%s'%y)

        m1 = np.square(np.arange(y+1))
        n1 = (y+1)*np.arange(y+1)
        fig2.subplot(3,2,y+1)
        fig2.plot(m1,n1, 'r')
        fig2.title('y=%s'%y)
fig1.show()
fig2.show()
```

This code doesn't work; gives me the error message that 'Figure' object has no attribute 'subplot'. I've tried many variations on this link - http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html, but I am unable to understand how to do it the right way.
In the output, I want two figure windows, each with 6 subplots, such that the first one contains plots of m vs n, and the second one contains plots of m1 vs n1.

Comment: I think you mean to use `fig1.add_subplot()` and `fig2.add_subplot()` rather than `fig1.subplot()` and `fig2.subplot()`.

Comment: This is just an example of the type of code I want to create. I am not quite sure which is the right way to do it. I went through a lot of examples given in the documentation and I am totally confused!

Comment: The matplotlib examples are infuriatingly inconsistent with their use of the object oriented and functional uses of matplotlib. `subplot()` is a member of `pyplot`, while `add_subplot()` is a member of a `figure` object.

Comment: Well, the error you are getting indicates that `Figure` instances do not have a method called `Figure.subplot()`.  It's the exact same error you would get if you tried to call `str.subplot()` and is an error you should learn quickly since it will come up quite a bit.

Comment: Like will points out, you can use either `Figure.add_subplot()` or `pyplot.subplot()`.  I would recommend always using `Figure.add_subplot()` since it explicitly adds a subplot to a specific `Figure` instance.

Comment: I am not good with object oriented programming, which is why I am having trouble understanding the right combinations to use. I tried add_subplot, but then I am getting the same error for the next statement, AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plot'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, long explanation because there are multiple issues here.

The biggest problem you are running into is that there are multiple ways to handle things in matplotlib.  In fact, there are effectively multiple interfaces.  The easiest and most commonly used method is to just create your plot using `pyplot` and its methods like `pyplot.subplot` and `pyplot.plot`.  This can work well for quick plots, but will not work well for your situation.

Since you want to create two figures and alternate plotting to those figures, you are going to want to use the more powerful objects in `pyplot`.  You have gotten part way there yourself, but I'll try to help you with the last part.

You are good up until here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nr = [10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 50]
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
for y in range(len(nr)):
    m = np.arange(y+1)
    n = (y+1)*np.arange(y+1)
```

but when you try to use the methods of `Figure`, you are getting confused and trying to use similar methods that belong to `pyplot`.  The next portion should be rewritten as:

```
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(3,2,y)
    ax1.plot(m,n, 'b')
    ax1.set_title('y=%s'%y)

    m1 = np.square(np.arange(y+1))
    n1 = (y+1)*np.arange(y+1)
    ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(3,2,y)
    ax2.plot(m1,n1, 'r')
    ax2.set_title('y=%s'%y)
```

Here, what you have done is capture the `Axes` instance that is returned from `add_subplot()`.  Then you plot onto the `Axes` instance.  Also, when specifying where you want the subplot to be placed (the third input to `Figure.add_subplot()`), you do not want to use `y+1` because that would start at `1` and end at `6` which would go out of the available range of 0-5.  Remember that Python indices start with zero.

Finally, to show the figures you just created, you can either call `pyplot.show()` like this:

```
plt.show()
```

or you can save the figures to files like this:

```
fig1.savefig('fig1.png')
fig2.savefig('fig2.png')
```

The resulting figures look like this:

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Although, when I'm specifying where I want the subplot to be placed, using y+1 is working for me. When I use y, I am getting this warning - MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The use of 0 (which ends up being the _last_ sub-plot) is deprecated in 1.4 and will raise an error in 1.5. I also read somewhere that indices for subplot start from 1. One strange thing in your solution is that your loop index seems to be starting from 1, as can be seen from the plots, since y, the loop index is in the title of the plots.

Comment: Just noticed, the last plot in your set of plots is the one for y=0, which means, according to the warning, the subplot with index 0 is taken as the last subplot. So, in this case, y+1 is indeed the correct usage.